# python run test with app installed from pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

For some of the python apps, if I install them manually, I can run `python setup.py test` inside the app folder to carry out test scripts. But if I install them through pip, there's only an .egg file in dist-packages, so how should I run their test?

Comment: Why would you want to run code tests when the package tool does that for you?

Comment: there will be two directory for each installed package. Did you check that?. One ends with .egg and another with original source files.

Comment: I installed pyelasticsearch, which only leaves an .egg file, no folder :(

Answer (score 3):

I did the following in a virtualenv and was able to run the tests.

```
$ pip install pyelasticsearch
$ pip install nose virtualenv scripttest mock
$ cdsitepackages #virtualenvwrapper shortcut to go to the site-packages directory
$ cd pyelasticsearch/tests
$ nosetests
```

Depending on where your site-packages directory is located you'll probably replace cdsitepackages with something else.  As @thaven mentioned, there are two directories created - one that pyelasticsearch-0.5-py2.7.egg-info/ and one that is pyelasticsearch.  If the pyelasticsearch package wasn't actually there, you wouldn't be able to import anything.